# Why does -istic turn some words negative?

Tags: etymology, suffixes

The definition of -istic is:

> Used to form adjectives from nouns, especially nouns in -ist and -ism, with the meaning "of or pertaining to" said nouns.

I don't see anything in there that could make words negative, but I can think of a few adjectives that are more negative with the suffix -istic. A few examples: negativistic, simplistic, moralistic, and legalistic.

Comment: I think many words, such as *feministic, moralistic, simplistic,* have relatively negative connotations compared to the "standard" versions *feminine, moral, simple*. For the first two of those, perhaps it's because the "intermediate" forms *feminist, moralist,* are often used disparagingly.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: yes, see my answer. The negative senses, where they exist, come from the connotation of an "*ist*" blindly, pigheadedly, and often superciliously subscribing to an "*ism*".  (BTW, I had written a comment here, but somehow it got deleted.)

Comment: @Dan: Sorry - I hadn't even noticed there were any answers here when I posted that. I see your thoughts went further than mine. I'm sure we've got a question somewhere on ELU where it's pointed out that ***-isms*** (particularly, "one-off" coinages) are often negative - and thus by implication, so are the associated ***-ists*** and their ***-istic*** tendencies.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: *it's not the "istic", it's the underlying "**ist**"*, or ultimately *ism*.

Let's examine your four examples:

- ***negativistic***: "[negativist](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/negativist)" + *ic*: being like someone who

  > *has a tendency to be **unconstructively critical***
- ***simplistic***: "[simplist](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=simplistic&searchmode=none)" + *ic*:  being like someone who

  > "*studies **simples***", which are  "*herbs used in healing, medicine of one ingredient only; the notion being that each herb possesses a particular virtue, thus a `simple' remedy*", thus ***a simplist is a person who subscribes to a theory which is over-simple, trying to explain too much by a single principle***
- ***moralistic***: "[moralist](http://www.memidex.com/moralizing)" + *ic*: being like someone who is

  > *given to **moralizing***, which (in the perjorative) is "***indulgence in moral pronouncements***; the exposition (often superficially) of a particular moral code"
- ***legalistic***: "[legalist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikilawyering#Negative_connotations)" + *ic*: being like someone who is

  > *like a goddamn **lawyer***

So each of these words, rather than directly ascribing a quality, is defining the trait in terms of *acting like an a -**ist***.  This is not obvious at first blush, because the *-ist* has been subsumed into the *-istic*, sometimes to the extent that modern English doesn't even have original *-ist* (or *-ism*) any longer, as in *simplism* and *simplist*.  But none the less, in each case, the etymology traces back to a form of "X-*ist*" + "*ic*": "*acting like or having the quality of an X-ist*".

So to the extent *-ist* s and *-ism* s often have negative, pejorative connotations, so do *-istic* s.  But while ists and isms *as a class* are charged with obdurate or doctrinaire (and often supercilious) qualities, whether *particular* ists and isms -- and by extension, *istics* -- do, depends on society's perception of that particular doctrine.

Consider the range of senses in *altru*-istic (positive: one who practices *altru*-ism), *sad*-istic (negative: one who follows *de Sade*), *art*-istic (neutral/descriptive or positive), *unart*-istic (neutral/descriptive or negative), *character*-istic (not even applicable, *because it doesn't derive from an ism*), *bolshev*-istic (positive in Soviet Russia, negative in McCarthyist America).  The overtones come from (society's perception of) the root *ism* in each word.

Answer (score 0):

All the following suffixes have Latin/Greek origins. Actually it appears they have no specific negative connotations in their past usage and word formation. These  suffixes are used with both to positive, neutral and negative words.

[-ist](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Ist&searchmode=none)

> - word-forming element meaning *"one who does or makes,"* also used to indicate adherence to a certain doctrine or custom, from French -iste and directly from Latin -ista, from Greek -istes, from -is-, ending of the stem of verbs in -izein, + agential suffix -tes. Variant -ister (as in chorister, barister) is from Old French -istre, on false analogy of ministre. Variant -ista is from Spanish, popularized in American English 1970s by names of Latin-American revolutionary movements.

[-istic](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Ist&searchmode=none)

> - adjectival suffix, from French -istique or directly from Latin -isticus, from Greek -istikos, which is adjective suffix -ikos (see -ic) added to noun suffix -istes (see -ist).

[-ism](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Ism&searchmode=none)

> - suffix forming nouns of action, state, condition, doctrine, from French -isme or directly from Latin -isma, -ismus, from Greek -isma, from stem of verbs in -izein. Used as an independent word, chiefly disparagingly, from 1670s.

Source:http://www.etymonline.com